# How to remove the slash in the where condition of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using in array in where conditions of Codeigniter.

But here I am not getting the exact result what I need actually ,here in where condition some slashes are adding .
Below is my code

```html
$comma_separated= implode("','", $ids);  // here i am getting ids
$this->db->select("car_id");
$this->db->where_in('car_id',array(stripslashes($comma_separated))); 
$query_second = $this->db->get_where("car_booking");
```

My last query is

```html
SELECT `car_id`
FROM `car_booking`
WHERE `car_id` IN('123\',\'14781')
```

Here stripslahses is not working in the where conditions .

Any suggestion ,thank you ...

Comment: `stripslashes` is string function. How did you apply this to array?

Comment: can you please echo $comma_separated= implode("','", $ids); ? and provide what you get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You cannot apply string functions to array. The below code might help you to solve your problem.</strike>

```
$this->db->select("car_id");

foreach ($comma_separated as $key=>$value) {
    $comma_separated[$key] = stripslashes($value);
}
$this->db->where_in('car_id',array(stripslashes($comma_separated))); 
$query_second = $this->db->get_where("car_booking");
```

*After your question edited*, you no need to pass $ids array into `$this->db->where_in`. So use this code will solve your problem.

```
//$comma_separated= implode("','", $ids);  // here i am getting ids
$this->db->select("car_id");
$this->db->where_in('car_id', array_map('stripslashes',$ids)); // incase you want to use stripslashes
$query_second = $this->db->get_where("car_booking");
```

Comment: yes array should be there ,instead of string .
I got it .
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Change from

```
$this->db->select("car_id");
$this->db->where_in('car_id',array(stripslashes($comma_separated))); 
$query_second = $this->db->get_where("car_booking");
```

to

```
$this->db->select("car_id");
$this->db->where_in('car_id',array_map('stripslashes',$ids)); 
$query_second = $this->db->get_where("car_booking");
```

Comment: @sradha : answer provided

Comment: No not working ,is this should be array $comma_separated ??

Comment: I have imploded it and made it to string 

 $comma_separated =  implode("','", $ids);

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

> $comma_separated= implode("','", $ids);
>
> $this->db->select("car_id");
>
> $this->db->where_in('car_id',$comma_separated,FALSE);    **// add FALSE as third parameter**
>
> $query_second = $this->db->get_where("car_booking");

It produce:

> SELECT `car_id` FROM `car_booking` WHERE `car_id` IN('123','14781')